# Can i use multiple PodAffiniy in my kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I have a pod that i want to run on the same node if possible as another one or at least to run in the same availability zone at first i thought that i can use podAffinity with preferredduringschedulingignoredduringexecution and two podAffinityTerm but it doesn't seem to work properly so i thought if i can run two podAffinity so that if the first one (run on the same host) is not possible so the second one (run on the same AZ) will take place.

Here is my deployment manifest :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-test-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-test-deployment
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-test-deployment
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - pod-test
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - pod-test
              topologyKey: "failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone"
      containers:
      - name: app-test
        image: app-test:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: yes, your idea should work. What error do you get? You should probably lower the _weight_ for the second term?

Comment: my pod was scheduled on another AZ i think this has to do with the weight  field?

Answer (score 2):

1. Set weight for `/zone` to 99
2. Replace `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` to `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` and when it fails - you will see what is causing it to go to another AZ. Once it works set back to `preferred`.

Also, are you trying to link the Affinity to the same deployment you posted? If so - your labels have a mismatch: `app: app-test-deployment` in deployment VS `app: pod-test` in podAffinityTerm.

Comment: pod-test is the label of the pod i want to run my app-test-deployment with on the same node